# Remove pagination in list.js when user clicks a link

Tags: jquery, pagination, listjs

I am using list.js to filter a list of elements along with pagination. To activate pagination the following has to be added. The object property page determines how many items are visible on each page. I want to deactivate pagination when a user clicks a link, i.e. remove it so all the items appear on one page and are not paginated. Is this possible?

```
 var options = {
            valueNames: ['packageid', 'categoryid',  'meta-package', 'meta-category', 'meta-brand', 'meta-company', 'meta-country'],
            page:24,
            plugins: [
                [ 'paging', {
                    name: "duja",
                    pagingClass: "bottomPaging",
                    innerWindow: 1,
                    outerWindow: 2
                } ]
            ]
        };

        var featureList = new List('products-list', options);
```

Comment: So confusing. Post a fiddle or a demo.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your code is set to display 24 items at a time (because you defined `page:24,`). You can't just leave this line out because by default list.js will set this value to 200, so the easy solution is to change the value to an extremely large number, e.g.

```
page:1000000;
```